# Clarion 6.3 + libcurl doesn´t work

Tags: curl, libcurl, clarion

I have the Clarion 6.3 version and after to follow the instructions from homepage i can see Clarion imported the libcurl to the system.

[`libcurl` for Clarion link](https://github.com/mikeduglas/libcurl/blob/master/examples/FormPost/FormPost.clw)

But after to create a window and a button, and put code above in the button source area it doesn't work, specially the line about to include the *.inc* file

```
PRAGMA('project(#compile libcurl.clw)')
PRAGMA('project(#pragma link(libcurl.lib))')

INCLUDE('libcurl.inc')
```

Someone could help me with that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like something other than plain text was pasted into the code. Try this:

```
  PRAGMA('project(#compile libcurl.clw)')
  PRAGMA('project(#pragma link(libcurl.lib))')

  INCLUDE('libcurl.inc')

  MAP
  END
```

Comment: Possibly an issue with line endings when downloading from GitHub? https://clarionhub.com/t/clarion-and-git-line-endings/161

Comment: As I recall it was UTF-16 or some such that the c6 IDE doesnt grok.